# moment split dates into 30 minutes interval

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two dropdowns `from` and `to` and user can select 30 minutes interval on any day.

I want something like following using moment js or using plain js

```
from [ 12:00am, 12:30am, 1:00am, 1:30am, 2:00am,...... ] till midnight
```

and to will can start from `12:30am`

**EDIT**

If I select 1:00am from start date, I want `to` dates from `1:30am`

how can I write that function? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var startDate = moment().startOf('day');

var dates = [];
var hourDivider = 2;
var t = hourDivider * 24;

while(t--) {
  dates.push(startDate.format('hh:mma'));
  startDate.add(60/hourDivider, 'minute');
}               
                
console.log(dates)

// answer to second question 

var fromIndex = 2; // 01:00am
var toDates = dates.slice(fromIndex+1);

console.log(toDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey updated question can you please help me with that? Thx

Comment: @noName do you want duration ? or you want `from` `to` dates ?

Comment: @noName ok you want to `to` date to show only valid values ?

Comment: yes, If in "from" I have 1:00 pm selected in to date I want to show only values from 1:30pm

Comment: it is super easy actually :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [add](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [is same or before](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/) to build the list